# TFS dividing merge into parts

Tags: tfs, merge, branch, tfvc

Let's assume I have 2 branches: *Dev* and *Prod*.

For example, I've changed *FileA.cs* and *FileB.cs* in Dev. I've launched merge from Dev to Prod, and now have both files in pending changes.

But, at the moment I want to push to Prod *FileA.cs* only. And *FileB.cs* should be pushed later.

The question is, what should I do with pending change for *FileB.cs*? If I will undo it, will this change appear again for next merge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **exclude** (right click the file, select exclude)`FileB.cs` in the pending changes. This is just like hangs on the file.

[image]

When you need it, just included the `FileB.cs`  back again.

Moreover, if you undo it, this change will still **appear again for next merge.**

Comment: Excluding isn't very usable in my case, as actually I have a few hundreds of changed files to exclude. And I don't want them to wait in excluded changes for month or two.
But Undo looks fine, thanks.